# Cannot verify password in PHP

Tags: php, hash, bcrypt, verify

On this project, I've used *BCRYPT* to make a hash off the password

On logging in, the user normally logging in without any errors or whatsoever, but when trying to change your password, your current password **does not** match with the password in the database (of course i'm using `password_verify()` to verify the two passwords)

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
  $option = ['cost' => 12];
  $password = password_hash($_currentpassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $option);

  $selectpasswordsql = "SELECT `password` FROM `auth` WHERE username=?";
  $selectpasswordstmt = $conn->prepare($selectpasswordsql);
  $selectpasswordstmt->execute(array($_SESSION['account']['username']));
  $selectpasswordresults = $selectpasswordstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $databasepass = $selectpasswordresults['password'];
  $databasepass = trim($databasepass);
  if(password_verify($password,$databasepass)){
    if(empty($passmsgs)){
      $updatepasssql = "UPDATE `auth` SET
        `password`=?
      WHERE username=?
      ";
      $updatepassstmt = $conn->prepare($updatepasssql);
      $updatepassstmt->execute(array($password, $_SESSION['account']['username']));
      if($updatepassstmt){
        array_push($passmsgs, 'Successfully updating your password!');
      } else {
        array_push($passmsgs, 'There was a problem executing your command!');
      }
    }
  } else {
    array_push($passmsgs, 'Your current password is wrong!');
  }
```

Trying this out will cause an error of not matching your current password with the password

---

**Edit**: Yes I am using `VARCHAR` with a maximum length of *255*

**Edit 2**: Here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/AXHyBXLj) to the full copy of my codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to hash your `$_currentpassword` variable in the second line.

Just pass the variable to the `password_verify` function and the function itself will do the job.

Comment: password_verify will hash my `current_password` so indeed it is needed. Why do you think tho that it is not needed?

Comment: I added a link to see my whole codes, check it if you need to

Comment: `password_varify` does what it needs to do, it doesn't require to hash password externally.
Just pass user submitted password and old password from DB, it should work.
for more : [password_varify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: and, I would suggest to use `varchar(500)` , just to be safe.

Comment: 500....... why? the manual suggests 255 is a good bet; never will password_hash produce anything beyond 255.

Comment: Thanks! As far as i'm concern about efficiency, `varchar(255)` is the best for low consuming space